# javascript for loop uploads only one file

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, file-upload

can anyone see where this for loop goes wrong ? i get no console errors, and it can upload single files just fine, but if i select multiple only one gets uploaded, have been at this all day and am getting really frustrated here.

```
handleFiles = function (files,e){
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+3);
var imageType = /image.*/;
var file = files[0];
for(var i=0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {  
alert("Filen er \""+file.name+"\" forkert printformat");
return false;   
} 
if (parseInt(file.size / 1024) > 204800) {  
    alert("Filen er \""+file.name+"\" for stor");
    return false;   
} 

var template = '<div class="eachImage" id="'+rand+'">';
    template += '<span class="preview" id="'+rand+'"><img src="'+file.name+'"><span class="overlay"><span class="updone"></span></span>';
    template += '</span>'
    template += '<div class="progress" id="'+rand+'"><span></span></div>';  

upload(file,rand);
}};
```

Any and all help is greatly apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `file` never changes. `f` gets updated, but you never use `f`. Why isn't the loop like this?

```
for(var i=0; file = files[i]; i++) {
```

Comment: this gives me a syntax error on the end parenthesis :S

Comment: All I can say is check your code and your typing carefully. What I showed is valid syntax. I just entered in to the console, closing the { with a }, and it works just fine.

Comment: i made it work with a modified for loop, but ill give you the answer as you are correct the above code is a proper for loop :) have a good weekend.

Comment: Good example of why favoring methods like forEach avoid issues.